# Why did the Hunter x Hunter manga quality randomly deteriorate?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In the manga [Hunter x Hunter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter), the manga is amazing up until around chapter 184, where the drawings start noticeably deteriorating to the point of scribbles.  This is fixed a little later, but every now and then the quality goes back down slightly.  Is there a reason for this?  Was the mangaka just pressed for time?

Comment: So wait, admins deleted an answer with image links and didn't move it to a comment? That's really useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He had several problems of health. His arms get illness, I heard. So, his wife (author of Sailormoon) helps him draw Hunter X Hunter. And other works, as usual, belong to assistant. 
That's why the quality is not the same over time.

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshihiro_Togashi#cite_ref-21);

> *Togashi suffered from an immense amount of stress while working on
>   YuYu Hakusho, which caused him inconsistent sleep patterns and chest
>   pain. Togashi has taken numerous breaks in recent years while writing
>   Hunter × Hunter, the first of which was due to illness*

But I think the storyline is still great, huh?

Comment: Ahhh I see.  I had no idea his wife was the author of sailor moon.  Yeah, the storyline is definitely still great, by far my favorite manga / anime (although I haven't seen the reboot).

Comment: Does anyone have pictures of the panels?